# When infinite scroll charge the loop other ajax are broken

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, scroll, infinite

**How to replace id in JS with the id of the button :**

> https://codepen.io/eddy-vuillaume/pen/yLBPXRd

```
  $('button').click(function(){
      $('.hide_'+id).hide(1000, function(){

      });
    });
```

Comment: actually what is your requirement ?

Comment: I have a infinite scroll and i charge <script> each while but it's broken.
I need to replace my data $id in php by id in JS

Comment: include jquery library and pass id.

Comment: I include jquery but how you get id ?

Comment: @EddyVuillaume check updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
  $(document).on( 'click', 'button', function(){
var id= $(this).attr('id');

  $('.hide_'+id).hide(1000, function(){
    alert('hide div class_'+id);
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hide_1">
  <p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="1">Bouton</button>
  </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae hic voluptate eum, sit possimus nostrum, ducimus beatae? Voluptatibus, harum. Modi error consectetur quasi alias quas obcaecati dolorem quam! Quisquam, impedit!</p>
</div>
<div class="hide_2">
  <p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="2">Bouton</button>
  </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae hic voluptate eum, sit possimus nostrum, ducimus beatae? Voluptatibus, harum. Modi error consectetur quasi alias quas obcaecati dolorem quam! Quisquam, impedit!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: any js conflict ?

Comment: You can try here : https://recette.jeux-concours-gagnants.com/test/index.php only first 10 results are ok

Comment: @EddyVuillaume please check updated answer. update js  if the issue exist please ping me

Comment: GREAT ! Thank you so much my friend!

Comment: with your pleasure... happy coding ;)

Comment: May be you can help me, how can i recognize 2 buttons whith different action (like, share for example)
I have <button id="1"></button>
If i have <button id="like_1"></button> and <button id="share_1"></button>

Comment: @Eddy please share your question link

Comment: You want i open a new question ?

Comment: Yes, add a new question please!

Comment: hai @EddyVuillaume did you add question ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this script. Please check the fiddle link.

```
$('button').click(function(){
  var id= $(this).attr("id");
  $('.hide_'+id).hide(1000, function(){

  });
});
```

[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/c3axqnw2/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this key word to get id attribute

```
$('button').click(function(){
  $('.hide_'+$(this).attr("id")).hide(1000, function(){

  });
});
```